# Automatic login with windows credentials

Tags: c#, angular, iis, .net-core, windows-authentication

I have built an .NET CORE project and I want it to automatically take my Windows credentials and login. Right now, my app prompts me to enter username and pass.
 Also, I have a back-end side for my app developed in Visual Studio and a front-end side built with Angular in Visual Studio Code. I'm using IIS.
 When I run the app, it prompts me on the server side and I need it to do that on client side. This should be done before fixing the prompting problem.

I have removed the "Anonymous authentication" in IIS and still doesn't work

How can I manage this?

This is my ISS setup

[image: this is my IIS setup]

also, in my code I have a file, launchSettings.json

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": true,
    "anonymousAuthentication": false,
    "iis": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost/CalendarApplication",
      "sslPort": 0
    },
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:57191/",
      "sslPort": 0
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IIS",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "CalendarApplication": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:57192/"
    },
    "Calendar_IIS": {
      "commandName": "IIS"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What does "prompt me on server side" mean? You open the website from the browser, and on the server a popup opens?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean

Comment: So you need to implement authentication, but I guess nobody will give you a step by step tutorial here, only support on specific questions.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of your IIS setup for the site?

Comment: What URL are you using? Windows authentication only happens automatically within the Intranet zone. if you're using an IP address, or a fully qualified URL then it does not happen unless you add that location to the intranet zone in IE.

Answer (score 0):

You need to disable anonymous authentication, what you already did.

Then you need to enable windows authentication.

[image]

For further information, look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webServer/security/authentication/)

Comment: I also did that